# How to use `__get__validator__(cls)` method of Pydantics

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I am using Pydantic to validate my payload. I have created a class like this -

```
class PayloadValidator(BaseModel):
    """
    This model validates the payload structure and each attribute of payload.
    """

    tenantId: str
    emailId: List[str]
    role: str
    # means the payload emails are duplicate.
    _duplicates: bool = False
    # means the emails in payload are already used for the requesting tenants.
    _existing:  bool = False
    # means the emails in payload are non corporate emails.
    _non_corp_emails: bool = False
    # final invite list
    _valid_emails = List[str]
```

I want to perform certain validations on emailId. So I wrote couple of methods -

```
def email_format(a):
    """
    raise an exception or return a tuple.
    """
    pass

def email_existance(a,b,c):
    """
    raise an exception or return a tuple.
    """
    pass

def duplicate_emails(a):
    """
    raise an exception or return a tuple.
    """
    pass
```

Now these function are in a different module and I want to sequentially use it in `__get__validator__(cls)` method of Pydantic.

The [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#classes-with-__get_validators__) says that I have to use `yeild`. How can I make it work with my use case?

Comment: Why don't you use regular validators for your model from which imported functions can be called?

Comment: like root_validator ?

Comment: Yes, root or per field validator

Comment: Yeah well as a work around I have done it like that. However, I am not sure if it is a good practice.

Comment: `__get__validators__` is used when one creates custom field type (not inherited from `BaseModel`)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below
lets say u want to validate payload for email_format method

```
from pydantic.validators import str_validator
class EmailValidation(str):
       @classmethod
       def __get_validators__(self):
           yield str_validator
           yield email_format
```

similarly u can validate other payloads too